# Update all grid dropdown list items on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoUI grid.
I want to add a little button icon thing to the column or edit template that when clicked would set all other dropdown menus on the current page to the selection made in that cell ONLY IF they haven't been set yet.

On click of the icon I need to cycle thru the other DDL's if the value = 1 then set to the value of the DDL beside the icon that was clicked.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative.

[image: Grid Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Editor template add events e.select

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Events(e => e.Select("setAllDropDownlist"))
    .DataSource(source => ...)  

)
```

********************javascript function****************

```
function setAllDropDownlist(e)
 { 
     var SelectedValue= this.dataItem(e.item.index()).ReasonName

     //loop on all the dropdownlist and check value but I don't recommend doing it
      $("select option").each(function() {
          if($(this).val() == SelectedValue) {
              $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
            }


       });  

    //loop one by one on each drop dropdownlist you want to set value

     $("#HowYouKnow option").each(function() {
     if($(this).text() == SelectedText) {
     $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
          }                        
    });


  }
```

Regards

## Shaz

Comment: And if i'm not using razor?
I am assigning the little icon the uid of the row and I want the onclick of the icon to trigger the setAllDropDownList function...
If existing value of any other dropdown is equal to 1 then set to the value of the dropdown in the row where the icon was clicked

Comment: In that case set hidden field value as selected value and on img click call a seperate javascript function and iterate options values against hidden field value...if you did'nt understand i'll edit my post???

Comment: Hey man I'm getting closer I think

http://jsbin.com/xiyet/3/edit

I have tried to loop thru the others but can't get it to work.

Comment: says I need 20 rep to use the room

Comment: I guess there is some lag between here and there it shows me as 16 rep there  ... gtalk? dgobrien@gmail.com skype text chat dgobrien_nc